# Dependencies problem in liferay 7.1 and npm-angular-portlet created by blade cli

Tags: angular, npm, liferay, bundler, liferay-blade-cli

i have a problem to add dependecies in a npm-angular-portlet created by blade cli (liferay 7.1, blade version 3.4.3.201901222323, liferay-npm-bundler: ^2.6.2). When i created the portlet i deployed it in liferay 7.1 and all was working good. Then i tried to add 2 dependecies in the package.json and add the relative import in hte app.module.ts: build is ok, the dependecies are inside the node_modules directory; but in runtime i found some message in the browser console saying that the added dependencies has some other dependencies not found in the server. So i tried to add also that dependencies but nothind changed, so i think that maybe i haven't understood where is the problem:
[image]
So i read some documentation on liferay about the liferay-npm-bundler and had a look inside the jar created by the gradle build process: i found the javascript dependecies, so i think the npm-bundler is working goos and i cannot understand where is the problem. 
Does anyone has a good tip for me? Is it necessary some additional operation to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: it is one thing if the file is included but it is another thing if it is actually in the AMD loader. Have a look in the AMD reagister if the lib got correctly registered.

Comment: Hi, it's a good tip.  How is it possibile to check the module registerd in the  AMD register? i have found the flix gogo shell command "scr:list"; is it right for this check? thanks

Comment: no this is not in the gogo shall. check it in chrome network tab or just open this file /o/js_loader_modules?t=1549923509288

Comment: There was some problems with peer dependencies. I solve that problem and i have no warning while build the project, but now the deploy the jar the process hangs up with no errors.. do you know how can i investigate the problems? thanks

Comment: Have you tried to delete the OSGi state? If yes then try to go to GOGO shell and see what the bundle is doing. Force to start it usualy prints some error if there is a problem.

Comment: Hi, ok i solved the peer dependecies problems, now the build and deploy process works good. 
Now i have this problem: when the portlet start i have 3 errors (http code 500) about 3 js dependencies. For first thing I had a look inside /o/js_loader_modules and that dependecies are included... 
The url of one of this js problematic dependencies is:
http://localhost:8080/combo/?browserId=other&minifierType=&languageId=en_US&b=7101&t=1541103248346&frontend-taglib-clay$clay-button@2.3.4/lib/ClayButton.js
Is it possible that the url is badly formed? Does anyone has a good idea? 
thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution in the end ? I am facing similar issue :(